# What does it mean for a joint PDF to be symmetric in its constituents?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function, bivariate-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent standard normal random variables and consider the following linear transformations, $$U = X$$ and $$V = \rho X + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}Y,$$ where $\rho \in (0, 1)$. Show that the joint density of $U$ and $V$ is symmetric in $u$ and $v$.

I have found the joint density to be $$
f_{U, V}(u, v) = \frac 1 {2\pi\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}} \exp\left\{-\frac {u^2 - 2\rho uv + v^2} {2(1 - \rho^2)}\right\}.$$

However, what does it mean to show that the joint density of $U$ and $V$ is symmetric in $u$ and $v$ and what is the simplest way to go about showing this? Can I just "observe"? Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Observe that $f(u,v) = f(v,u)$.

Comment: @fwd how does one "observe" this? Do you mean to say simply substitute $u$ for $v$ and $v$ for $u$ in my joint density?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: @fwd right! Thank you :) Although it may be short, you may want to consider posting this as an answer since it technically answers my question, so that I can accept it and the post may be closed and people will not comment further on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to observe that $f(u,v) = f(v,u)$. A function being symmetric in $k$ variables means that it is unchanged for any permutation of the variables.